# Customizing Search Filter and Calendar Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I got a search field but I want to customize the text hint it presents like "Search" I want to change it to my language which would be "Busca" how to do that in the code below:

```
Container list = new Container();
hi.getToolbar().addSearchCommand(e -> {
    String text = (String)e.getSource();
    if(text == null || text.length() == 0) {
        // clear search
        for(Component cmp : list) {
            cmp.setHidden(false);
            cmp.setVisible(true);
        }
        hi.getContentPane().animateLayout(150);
    } else {
        text = text.toLowerCase();
        for(Component cmp : list) {
            Button mb = (Button)cmp;
            String line1 = mb.getText();
            boolean show = line1 != null && line1.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1;
            mb.setHidden(!show);
            mb.setVisible(show);
        }
        hi.getContentPane().animateLayout(150);
    }
}, 4);
```

By the way how do I set a Codename One Calendar to be presented in my local language?

**EDITED:**

I watched the tutorial, but I'm having issues, I think I'm not setting it properly, look:
[image: theme.res]

and this is what I wanna change:

[image: Search filter]

Should I set something like this?

```
hi.putClientProperty("Search", hi.getToolbar());
```

My code below:

```
String lang = L10NManager.getInstance().getLanguage();
        if(lang != null) {
            lang = lang.toLowerCase();
            switch(lang) {
            case "en":
                UIManager.getInstance().setBundle(theme.getL10N("portuguese", "pt"));
                break;
            }
        }
```

I'm getting exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.consultaprodutos.AplicacaoPrincipal.init(AplicacaoPrincipal.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:118)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1129)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:924)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

**OBS: I couldn't find VM Options in my Project Properties in order to set -Defuser.language=pt**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this tutorial on localization](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---localizetranslate-my-application-apply-i18nl10n-internationalizationlocalization-to-my-app.html). The gist of it is that you create a resource bundle and install it then everything automatically updates to the new localized text.

The keys match the text so if the text is "Search" just add "Search" to the resource bundle and the translation value.

Comment: Edited my question, I'm missing something I guess.

Comment: What's in line 76? Which ide are you using?

Comment: Eclipse, in line 76 there is `UIManager.getInstance().setBundle(theme.getL10N("portuguese", "pt"));`

Comment: It looks like `theme` is null. How do you initialize it?

Comment: I initialize it by `UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "Business");`

Comment: Thanks Shai, I set `theme = UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "Business");` it's working as intended, I got Calendar and Search translated.